# How to extend the DropDownListFor() in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to extend DropDownListFor in such a way that to preserve the original functionality, but add the functionality that if the selected value that is given is Null, to a new value to the SelectListItem list such as 'Select an item'.

How would you do that?

**EDIT: (I wasn't clear at the beginning)**

If we look at the default DropDownListFor behavior, the extension gets a list of SelectItems and the 'selected' value.
In my app, sometimes the 'selected' value is Null, thus no option is selected from the SelectItems list.
I would like to change the default behavior in such a way, that if my 'selected' value is Null, then the DropDown will add automatically a new value such as 'Select an Item' and select it as the 'selected'.

Hope it's better now :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want validation mechanism prompts the user that an item must be selected?

Comment: No. Just the usual Dropdown list with a new item. I want the DropDown to check if the selected value is null and then add that item. that's all

Comment: Why do you include a null value as an option to begin with? It's no clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JohnMighty I guess you are not clear with your requirement, please rethink about your requirement and edit your question

Comment: Sorry guys, I hope it's better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Did it!
For future reference here is the solution:

I've create an extension method for the DropDownListFor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString KeywordDropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
                                                   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)
{
    Func<TModel, TValue> method = expression.Compile();
    string value = method(helper.ViewData.Model) as string;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        List<SelectListItem> newItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        newItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = true,
            Text = Strings.ChooseAKeyword,
            Value = String.Empty
        });
        foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList)
        {
            newItems.Add(item);
        }

        return helper.DropDownListFor(expression, newItems, htmlAttributes);
    }

    return helper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: I use above code but the following errors occurred

does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and no extension method 'DropDownListFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is good answer, but one important thing is missed. You need to add using System.Web.Mvc.Html; in order to make it work.